# my bot is working properly but still not responding to my commands

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
my code
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const prefix = '$';
const client = new Discord.Client({
'intents': [
GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages
]
});

client.once('ready', () => {
console.log('- - - - -');
console.log('bot is online!');
console.log('- - - - -');
});

client.on('message', message => {
if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

        const args = message.content.split(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
        const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

        if(command === 'ping'){
        message.channel.send('pong');
    }
    });

client.login('TOKEN');
```

before i even got my bot online i had a problem with gatewayintentbits and after hours of figuring it out and running my bot it finally got online but when i added my first command it doesnt respond even after chaning prefix and adding multiple gateways i need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slash commands are generally recommended instead of text commands nowadays. The event is `messageCreate`, not `message`. You probably don't have the message content intent set to true in your [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications/). I strongly recommend you follow the [official Discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/).

This code should work if you have the message content intent.

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const prefix = '$';
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages
    ]
});

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('- - - - -');
    console.log('bot is online!');
    console.log('- - - - -');
});

client.on('messageCreate', message => {
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
 
    const args = message.content.split(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'ping'){
        message.channel.send('pong');
    }
});

client.login('TOKEN');
```